# JS / PHP Uploading index's and setting a div to a picture

Tags: javascript, php

Right now I have this code:

```
function addButton() {
    var button1 = "<div id=\"number\" class=\"inner\" style=\"display:inline-block; margin-top:5px; margin-right: 5px;\"><p></p></div>"              // Create text with HTML
        var button2 = button1.replace("number", number)
        $("#buttonz").append(button2);     // Append new elements
        number += 1
};

window.onload = addButtons;
var slots = '<?php echo $slots ?>';
var s = 0;
function addButtons() {
    for (i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
        addButton();
    }

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#buttonz').on('click', '.inner', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected inner");
        $('#meem').text(++s);
        $('#price').text((s * <?php echo $ticketPrice ?>).toFixed(2));


    });

    $('#buttonz').on('click', '.selected', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected inner");
        $('#meem').text(--s);
        $('#price').text((s * <?php echo $ticketPrice ?>).toFixed(2));

    });

});


}

function buySlots() {
    if ((s * <?php echo $ticketPrice; ?>).toFixed(2) > <?php echo $credits; ?>) 
    {
        alert('You do not have enough money...');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('You have enough money...');
    }
}
```

This code is part of the code that makes this: http://csgolessons.com/big-raffle.php (You have to login through steam)

I have the selection and price sorted out, but I want people to be able to select X amount of slots, press a button (that makes #ofslots * price be deducted from your account) and then replaces it with a picture I have stored in my database.

I have a database that looks like this (picture url isn't actually insertlink.com):

```
id   |   isTaken   |   pictureURL   |
1          0         insertlink.com
2          0         insertlink.com
3          0         insertlink.com
...
145        0         insertlink.com
```

What I want to know is how do I make the squares have a picture instead of the "inner" class?

How do I make a php file that would upload which buttons had been selected?

Thanks, and if you need clarification just ask.